# Replace cards from bottom of the deck

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, collections

I am a beginner to java and have created a 2 class program "VideoPoker" that basically mimics a one-person 5 draw game. In this game, a deck of cards is shuffled and the top 5 cards (of the now shuffled deck) are used to play 5 draw. The user can remove some, all, or none of the 5 cards he/she is given when the cards are dealt. If the user removes a card, it will be removed and replaced with the *next* top card. I am stuck at the point where a user decides to remove a card. In my program, when someone removes **all of the cards** or sometimes even only some, card #2 (index 1) and card #4 (index 3) always stay in the next hand (5 cards) print. My attempt is in the code *PICTURE BELOW*:

Deck.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {
    // Constructing a deck from two arrays
    String[] suit = { "C", "D", "H", "S" };
    String[] rank = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };
    ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>(suit.length * rank.length);
    int currentCard = 0;

    // Storing public variables
    int suits = suit.length;
    int ranks = rank.length;
    int deckSize = deck.size();

    // Constructs a deck with 52 cards
    public Deck(){
        for(int i = 0; i < suits; i ++){
            for(int j = 0; j < ranks; j++){
                String temp = rank[j] + suit[i];
                deck.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        return Arrays.deepToString(deck.toArray());    
    }

    // Fisher-Yates Shuffle 
    public ArrayList<String> shuffle(){
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
        return deck;
    }

    public String deal(){
        return deck.get(currentCard++);
    }

    public String remove(int i){
        return deck.remove(i);
    }

    public String get(int i){
        return deck.get(i);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList(){
        return deck;
    }
}
```

Dealer.java (tester program):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dealer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        Deck testDeck = new Deck();

        System.out.println(testDeck);

        testDeck.shuffle();

        System.out.println(testDeck);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
            System.out.print(testDeck.deal() + " "); 
        }

        String choice;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.print("\nWould you like to remove card " + (i + 1) + "? ");
            choice = in.next();
            if (choice.equals("Y")){
                testDeck.remove(i);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
           System.out.print(testDeck.get(i) + " ");  
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Just as an aesthetic note, you might consider replacing `10` with `T`, so that the ranks are all one character.

Comment: Try removing card 1 several times or displaying the hand after each card is removed. That will give a fair Idea of what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.print("\nWould you like to remove card " + (i + 1) + "? ");
    choice = in.next();
    if (choice.equals("Y")){
        testDeck.remove(i); // <-- removing the 'i'th element is the problem
    }
}
```

In this block you are asking the user if they want to remove the card at a certain position, but consider this.. If the user says, "Yes! I want to remove the first card!", you remove the top card at index 0 which is fine. But it's also where the problem arises because now you have a completely new deck! The card that was previously at index 1 (in your example it was the 10 of Hearts) is now actually at index 0. So in essence you are treating the deck like it is never changing when in reality it has the possibility to dynamically change and you are not accounting for this in your code.

**A possible (albeit crude) solution**:

```
// a list used to store the index of cards to be removed    
ArrayList<Integer> indexesToRemove = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.print("\nWould you like to remove card " + (i + 1) + "? ");
    choice = in.next();
    if (choice.equals("Y")) {
        indexesToRemove.add(i); // record index of card to be removed
    }
}

// here we remove the cards all at once    
for(int i = 0; i < indexesToRemove.size(); i++) {
    // each iteration is a guaranteed removal so
    // we subtract by i to counteract for each subsequent removal
    testDeck.remove(indexesToRemove.get(i) - i);
}
```

Comment: im agree to your first explanation but in `To solve:` what if he remove all ?  look at the printscreen. he already remove all the cards and still get the same cards.

Comment: You're right, my to solve is not correct - editing now

Comment: he is removing a card from his deck not on players card. hope this will help to improve your answer :)

Comment: he should separate the deck and players hand card. try to use map. map the player and the list of their current cards on hand. `Map<playerName, cardList);`

Comment: Yes - after he `deals` the top 5 cards are still at the top of the deck

Comment: @Secondo map is not allowed for this project unfortunately

Comment: then use/create another ArrayList for player handCard or another available collections.

Comment: @bewgs this makes sense - I'll try it out as soon as possible and choose this answer if all goes well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes down to the way you implement the deck logic. Instead of using the ArrayList to store your cards, and then indexing through it, you should use an ArrayDeque (pronounced "array deck") to handle the storage and removal logic.

You should track the contents of the player's hand separately from the deck; the main probem is in the way you have the deck and player hand coupled. By making your program more general, you can remove much of the complexity.

In the same vein of making the program more general, you should also use a separate class to handle cards. Doesn't need to be fancy though: just two public final fields, a constructor, and a toString method.